# Php, Sql group by multiple colums with sum()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$select = $pdo->prepare("select * from tbl_class c

          LEFT JOIN ( SELECT titile,subpid,sub_name, FROM tbl_subject)s ON s.subpid=c.subfkey

          LEFT JOIN ( SELECT markpid,mark_studetpid,mark_year,mark_subpid,mark_mark,mark_category FROM tbl_mark)m 
          ON c.studentfkey=m.mark_studetpid

          where $id=c.studentfkey and s.subpid=m.mark_subpid and m.mark_category ='A' order by m.mark_year desc ");
```

the output is like this now

| Class ID | subject Name | Mark year | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | maths | 2021 | 20 |
| 20 | chemistry | 2019 | 30 |
| 20 | chemistry | 2019 | 80 |
| 10 | maths | 2018 | 25 |
| 10 | maths | 2018 | 25 |
| 20 | chemistry | 2018 | 60 |

But i would like to have the results like this Grouping By year and subject and sum of marks yearly for each subjects

| Class ID | subject Name | Mark year | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | maths | 2021 | 20 |
| 20 | chemistry | 2019 | 110 |
| 10 | maths | 2018 | 50 |
| 20 | chemistry | 2018 | 60 |

I tried to add **group by m.mark_year,m.mark_subpid** but the sum is not counting well.

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY ClassID,subjectName,Markyear` and in SELECT change  to `SUM(Mark)` Make the column selection explicit instead of SELECT *

Comment: i did already but not some mark years are missing

Comment: Left JOIN a temprary table or a SELECT with all the years.

Comment: can you write an example?. i dnt understand...

Comment: $select = $pdo->prepare("select * from tbl_class c

          LEFT JOIN ( SELECT titile,subpid,sub_name, FROM tbl_subject)s ON s.subpid=c.subfkey

          LEFT JOIN ( SELECT classIdfkey ,subjectName,Markyearmarkpid,mark_studetpid,mark_year,mark_subpid,mark_mark,sum(mark) as score,mark_category FROM tbl_mark  Group By classIdfkey , subjectName, Markyear)m 
          ON c.studentfkey=m.mark_studetpid

          where $id=c.studentfkey and s.subpid=m.mark_subpid and m.mark_category ='A' order by m.mark_year desc ");

Comment: its working but missing some years

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN(SELECT 2010 year UNION SELECT 2011 UNION SELECT 2012 UNION.....) as years On years.year = whatever.markyears` This is called a calendar table to fill in missing dates,so you have all years that you can group by

Answer (score 0):

```
--drop table #Maths (Active it to run in SQL for multiple times)
create table #Maths
(
ClassID int,
SubjectName nvarchar(100),
MarkYear int,
Mark int (change to decimal(12,2) if needed)
)
--drop table #Chemistry (Active it to run in SQL for multiple times)
create table #Chemistry
(
ClassID int,
SubjectName nvarchar(100),
MarkYear int,
Mark int (change to decimal(12,2) if needed)
)

insert into #Maths
select ClassID, SubjectName, MarkYear, sum(Mark) from tbl_class a
LEFT JOIN tbl_subject B ON B.subpid=A.subfkey
LEFT JOIN tbl_mark C ON A.studentfkey=C.mark_studetpid
where SubjectName = 'Maths'

insert into #Chemistry
select ClassID, SubjectName, MarkYear, sum(Mark) from tbl_class a
LEFT JOIN tbl_subject B ON B.subpid=A.subfkey
LEFT JOIN tbl_mark C ON A.studentfkey=C.mark_studetpid
where SubjectName = 'Chemistry'

select ClassID, SubjectName, MarkYear, Mark from #Maths
union all
select ClassID, SubjectName, MarkYear, Mark from #Chemistry
order by MarkYear desc
```

try this. just try change with your own Columns or Tables name

Answer (score 0):

If grouping within the query is not desired, try making it with PHP (not recommended for big data).

First make an array to sum up marks on iterations

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object ($response)) {
   $marks[$row->classId][$row->year] += $row->mark;
}
```

Then use it to build up the table.

PS: sorry for showing mysql function, just forgot how to make the same in PDO. But it's an example.